# Как преобразовать число 100000 в 100.000

Tags: php

нужна помощь в преобразование числа с 100000 в 100.000 с помощью php

Дело в том что по API я получаю число без точки например такие числа как 8480000 это число 8.48, 1000000 это число 100.000 и тд.

Как можно к этим числа добавлять точки в нужно месте ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: Что-то я не понял, по какому принципу выбирается нужное место для точки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$number = 100000;
$formatted_number = number_format($number, 0, '.', '.');
echo $formatted_number; // Output: 100.000
```